# a:hover:before not centering on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I"m using the following code to create a rollover on my images on this page: atheniangrill.com/products/

```
#hovertext a {
    display: list-item;
    list-style: outside none none;
    position: relative;
}

#hovertext a:hover:before {
animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-duration: 0.8s;
}

#hovertext a:hover:before {
  content: '';
 display:block;
  background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/roastedredpepper.jpg');
  width: 100%; /* image width */
  height: 100%; /* image height */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

On mobile and iPad however, when you roll over the images, they aren't centered and float off to the side. I know I can make a @media only screen, but I'm not sure what to change in the coding.

Comment: I'm not big with mobile devices, but I have a hunch that :hover isn't going to work, try :focus instead.

Comment: I see this behaviour as well in Chrome on desktop. Why don't you use the different `background-image` on hover of the `#hovertext a` instead of the `:before` element. Can you please provide an extract of your code using CodePen or JSFiddle, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Roy, good idea- I redid the coding to include background images on the elements instead of using the a:hover method since I wasn't linking anything anyway.

Comment: And, have you resolved your question?

Comment: @Roy I don't know how :P